# Java - why the system.exit(0) is not getting executed?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7

Any idea why this system.exit(0) is not getting executed after executing the sendTCPBytes1 to localhost?

```
  public static void killerButton() throws IOException {
    String myCmd;          
    if (C.getOs().equals("Linux")) {
    } else {      
      System.out.println("[bug]: forceclose");
      sendTCPBytes1("forceclose", "localhost");   

      System.exit(0);
    }
  }


  public static void sendTCPBytes1(String filmfr2, String localhost) throws IOException {
    String downloaded = null;
    Socket socket = new Socket(localhost, 58888);
    DataOutputStream upload = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader download = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String c = filmfr2;
    upload.writeBytes(c);
    upload.flush();
    String get;
    downloaded = download.readLine();
    System.out.println("[TCP]: FROM server: >>> " + downloaded);
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. What's `C`? Where's `killerButton` called from?

Comment: how do you know that it's not being called?

Comment: Did you get an exception in `sendTCPBytes1`?

Comment: Do you see the output of `System.out.println("[TCP]: FROM server: >>> " + downloaded);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your socket connection fails e.g. throws an IOException, System.exit(0) will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this actually works the way I think it does, `readLine()` is a blocking call. If you never receive any input, it will wait there indefinitely.